# Is it natural for clouds to flow near the surface?

Tags: atmosphere, clouds

A week ago, I have seen something that I have never seen before, Nah it's not a flying dragon, but clouds that were flowing so near my roof (about 5-6 meters above my roof). These are the pictures, I have taken

[image]

Some of the clouds were passing just above the tree. I just want to know if this is a natural scene that occurs very often. What's the reason for clouds to flow so close to the surface?

---

Edit: My current location is 25 degrees N and 80 degrees E. it's better to call fog but they weren't stationary they were flowing quite fast from east-north to south-west. I'm attaching a couple of pictures. In the picture, the clouds are passing through that tower. Few more things to add, I'm living in the middle of the city, not in the mountains where this scenery might be seen very often. What I want is an explanation of these clouds? How they are flowing so near?

Comment: Can you provide your location?  Or at least your elevation?

Comment: Fog is essentially a low cloud. A very low cloud.

Comment: @farrenthorpe I live Fatehpur, UP India. That's 25 degrees N and 80 degrees E.  The elevation is 110m

Comment: @YoungKindaichi You could also add that there is a cyclone near your area

Answer (score 1):

I believe it had been raining before. The water had gone to the soil, but the moment you took that picture, it was already evaporating. The air was filling with such water coming from the soil, but air can hold only a limited quantity of gas water, so no more water could be in the form of gas (at so called "point of saturation"). Thus, it changed its state of matter from gas to liquid. But as we all now, liquid water can be seen (the "gas" above the boiling water that we can see is actually liquid water that rapidly cools down). Also, clouds are just such liquid water caught in the air, thus a cloud formed.

[image: Diagram of process]

The other near surface clouds can also form near the sea, with orographic clouds, descending of cloud, or on a front.

Answer (score 0):

Clouds are heavy. Clouds are a form of stored water, surfing the warm low pressure rising from the Earth's surface, if it weren't for the low pressure constantly rising above the denser high pressure, the clouds would naturally sink to the ground. This is what happens of foggy mornings, where there isn't sufficient low pressure to keep the clouds afloat.

What you're witnessing is a sort of intermediary stage where there is an updraft of low pressure, but not enough to keep the clouds high in the sky, so they sink as low as they can to the ground.

Comment: I believe that it has to do more with the evaporation of the water from the soil. The advection had moved the clouds away, thus leaving clear sky with before mentioned condensing evaporating water. Also, the weight of clouds has nothing to do here (everything in the form of ordinary matter has some weight, thus this is here unnecessary).